# How to send file mail

Tags: php, email, laravel

I have a system in laravel and I need to have a document attached to the server to  be sent by e-mail, either by creating it form laravel or attaching it directly to an Outlook.

Does anyone know how to do it ?

Comment: Please add what you tried to do.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Laravel mail inline attachment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#inline-attachments

```
<body>
    Here is an image:

    <img src="<?php echo $message->embed($pathToFile); ?>">
</body>
```